# ui-router prevent transitionTo to reload parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a basic search - results page. This is my ui-router config:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/search.html',
            controller: 'searchController'
        })
        .state('search.results', {
            url: '/results/:searchParameters',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/results.html',
            controller: 'resultController'
        });
```

This is how I send parameters from search to search.results that actually performs the GET

```
    $scope.search = function () {
        if (!$state.is('search.results')) {
            $state.go('search.results', { searchParameters: $scope.searchParameters });
        }
        else {
            $state.transitionTo('search.results', { searchParameters: $scope.searchParameters }, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
        }
    };
```

and this is my search.html

```
<div class="row">
    <form name="parameters" role="form" class="form-search" novalidate>
        <input type="text" class="form-control uppercase" placeholder="Codice manifestazione" 
               ng-enter="search()" ng-model="searchParameters.maniCode" />
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Anno" 
               ng-enter="search()" ng-model="searchParameters.year" maxlength="4" required/>
        <br />
        <label>Stato manifestazioni:</label>
        <select ng-enter="search()" ng-model="searchParameters.open" ng-init="searchParameters.open = true">
            <option value="true">Aperte</option>
            <option value="false">Chiuse</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Cerca" class="btn btn-default" 
               ng-click="search()" 
               ng-disabled="(parameters.$invalid || parameters.$pristine) || (clicked && !loaded)"/>
        <input type="button" value="Esporta in Excel" class="btn btn-default"
               ng-click="excelMain()"
               ng-disabled="(parameters.$invalid || parameters.$pristine) || (clicked && !loaded)" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <ul class="noStyleUl">
            <li ng-show="searchParameters.year.length < 4">Inserisci un anno per abilitare la ricerca</li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <div ui-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately $state.transitionTo will not only reload search.results (good) but also reload search (bad!), thus cleaning my form.

What I did right now is to send an event from ResultsController to SearchController in order to restore the scope and thus "refilling" the form. I'd like to know if there's a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that at the time you didn't know about services. Just use a Service! your model will remain as a singleton bindable from anywhere you have a reference to it. This way you won't have to worry if ui-router makes 1 or 3 instances of the controller.